# When the frame become too small, the buttons in a panel are hidden

Tags: api, awt, java

I use a class that `extends Frame` and in the constructor after defining all the propriety of the new Frame i append with the `BorderLayout.SOUTH` a new `Panel` that contains some buttons.

When I reduce the size of the Frame, if the space for the buttons isn't enough some of these disappear from the Frame.

How can I fix this problem?

```
public AdventureUI(Tappa tappa){
 setTitle("Adventure Game");
 //DIMENSIONE STANDARD DELLA FINESTRA       
 setSize(700,500);
 setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400,300));
 pannelloPrincipale = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
 pannelloBottoni = new Panel();
 testoTappa = new TextArea(tappa.toString(),25,50,TextArea.SCROLLBARS_NONE);
 testoTappa.setEditable(false);
 testoTappa.setBackground(new Color(211,211,211));
 areaUtente = new TextArea("",25,30,TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
     //ADD BUTTONS TO PANEL
 setBottoni(pannelloBottoni,tappa.getTappeCollegate());
 //AGGIUNGIAMO ELEMENTI AL PANNELLO PRINCIPALE
 pannelloPrincipale.add(testoTappa,BorderLayout.CENTER);
 pannelloPrincipale.add(areaUtente,BorderLayout.EAST);
 //AGGIUNGIAMO PANNELLI AL FRAME
 add(pannelloPrincipale,BorderLayout.CENTER);
 add(pannelloBottoni,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 // ASCOLTATORE FINESTRA 
 addWindowListener(new AdventureUIListener());
 setVisible(true);
}
```

Images of the problem:
[image: Normal size]

[image: smaller size]

As you can see the button with 26 is hidden.

Comment: Can you show more code

Comment: I add the constructor of the Frame

Comment: You shouldn't set the size. Just `pack()`

Comment: The buttons should always appear. Space is first taken from the component added to the "CENTER" of the BorderLayout.

Comment: The trouble is on `pannelloBottoni`

Comment: Can you post a compilable example of the problem?

Comment: It is only the UI of the program, there are other several classes and file that must be read for the correct execution

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see the button with 26 is hidden.

Yes that is because a FlowLayout always displays components at their preferred size. If there is not enough room then the component wraps to the next line, but unfortunately the height of the panel is not increased so you don't see the button.

Check out the [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/), it was designed to handle this situation. That is it will recalculate the height of the panel so all the buttons are displayed on multiple lines. At least it works with Swing. I've never test it with AWT because most people don't use AWT anymore.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I have to use only java official api.

Comment: @RiccardoPasianotto, then you won't be able to solve your problem because there are no layouts included with the JDK that will automatically wrap components to the next line.

Comment: @RiccardoPasianotto `I never say that I want a next line...`, So what do you expect to happen? We are not mind readers.

Comment: @RiccardoPasianotto, give a proper requirement!!! There is no space to paint the buttons that is why they disappear!!! So what do you want to happen? Do you want the space between the buttons to disappear? Do you want the buttons to shrink to that the text on the buttons disappear. Do you want a scrollbar to appear so the user can scroll to see all the buttons? Give us a reasonable requirement and then maybe somebody can help.

Comment: Then try a `GridLayout` is the easiest or maybe a `BoxLayout`. You would need to override the minimum size of the buttons to allow them to shrink. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples of each layout.